# Extra rows in dynamic table populated from SQL Server 2012 and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2012, html-table

I am generating a dynamic table, from the databasw (SQL Server 2012) using php. Using the code pasted below :

```
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tb">
            <tr style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: DarkGrey ">
                <th colspan="4" style="text-align:Center;">Objectives and Targets </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr-header">
                <th>Objectives / Measures</th>
                <th colspan="2">Targets / Achievements / Timelines</th>
                <th style="text-align:Center;width:1%;" rowspan="2">Weightage %</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> </th>
                <th> </th>
                <th style="width:10%;"> Date </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                    <?PHP
                        $myquery="  select replace(Objectives, '||<==', '') as Objectives, replace(Targets, '==', '') as Targets, replace(Weightage, '==', '') as Weightage, Corporate_Objective, Corporate_Objective_Weightage from Appraisal_Objectives WHERE Serial_Number='$Serial_Number' ORDER BY Row_Number asc";
                        $fetched=sqlsrv_query($conn,$myquery) ; 
                        if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
                        while($res=sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {   
                            $Corporate_Objective=$res['Corporate_Objective'];
                            $Weightage=$res['Weightage'];
                            $Objectives=$res['Objectives'];
                            $Targets=$res['Targets'];
                            $Corporate_Objective_Weightage=$res['Corporate_Objective_Weightage'];
                            echo "<tr><td>".$Corporate_Objective."</td>";
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "<td><b>".$Corporate_Objective_Weightage."</b></td></tr>";
                            echo "<tr><td>".$Objectives."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$Targets."</td>";
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$Weightage."</td></tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

> **Issue**

The output is creating many unwanted, blank rows inbetween each row! I haven't added any `<br/>` or and extra row in the code. Also, the rows in the databse do not have any spaces.

[image]

Where could I have gone wrong. Appreciate any help/suggestion. Thanks in advance.

> ScreenShot of the dynamic table output

[image]

Comment: `<tr FONT` <= what's what?

Comment: Sorry, that's a small error. Edited it.

Comment: have you had a look at your HTML source? It's also a "tool" ;-)

Comment: use prepared statements man! Also, give us the outputted html so we can see what causes your error.

Comment: I have attached the HTML source and the output's screenshot too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my SQL Query and used **COALESCE**. The code is as below :

```
select Targets,target_date,ROW_NUMBER,
COALESCE(Corporate_Objective,Objectives) AS Objectives,
COALESCE(Corporate_Objective_Weightage,Weightage) AS Weightage
FROM Appraisal_Objectives WHERE Serial_Number like '%1153';
```

This removed all the spaces in the table :

[image]